# Como imprimir "*" en vez de 0 en un matriz Java?

Tags: java, array

Tengo una matriz de 5 x 5 en la cual estoy mostrando la diagonal de dicha matriz, lo cual lo hace correctamente, pero muestra los valores que no son de la diagonal de la matriz en 0 y lo que busco es mostrar un "*" en vez de 0, ¿Cómo lo puedo lograr?

Resultado actual de la matriz

```
0   0   0   0   0   
0   6   0   0   0   
0   0   12  0   0   
0   0   0   18  0   
0   0   0   0   24
```

Codigo:

```
public int[][] CuartoEjercicio(int [][] arrayCuartoEjercicico){
    int Valor = 0;
    for(int i= 0; i < arrayCuartoEjercicico.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < arrayCuartoEjercicico[i].length; j++){
            arrayCuartoEjercicico[j][j] = Valor ++;
            System.out.print(arrayCuartoEjercicico[i][j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    return arrayTercerEjercicico;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es que quieres cambiar los `0` por `*`, al ya imprimir los datos es solo comparar si es que el índice `i`, es igual al de `j`, significa que ese dato en parte de la diagonal principal, de no ser así se tiene que imprimir un `*`:

Hice la siguiente matiz :

```java
int [][] matriz = {{2,4,4,7,1},{6,3,9,7,4},{8,10,12,45,17}, {1,7,5,3,8}, {9,11,14,7,2}};
```

Por lo cual la diagonal debería de ser:

> 2 - 3 - 12 - 3 - 2

Con el siguiente método realicé la identificación de la diagonal y a su vez cambie los demás números que no pertenecen a la diagonal por `*`

```java
public static void CuartoEjercicio(int[][] arrayCuartoEjercicico) {

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayCuartoEjercicico.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arrayCuartoEjercicico[i].length; j++) {
                if(i==j){ //si es que es parte de la diagonal se imprime el numero
                    System.out.print(arrayCuartoEjercicico[i][j] + "\t");
                }else{ //si no es parte de la diagonal se imprime un *
                    System.out.print("*" + "\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }    
}
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]